# T-SQL JOIN to get max value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First up can I apologise in advance as I know there are loads of questions and answers about this but I simply cannot get my head around it!

I have a table which contains a customer reference number `[MT-CODE]`, an invoice reference number `[REFERENCE]` and a date `[POST-DATE]` which I can use `DATEDIFF` on to see if the bill is overdue.

The columns `[MT-CODE]` and `[REFERENCE]` are not unique and so when I want to see if any of the invoices are overdue I can use grouping with the idea that I get one row per `[REFERENCE]`.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], 
    DATEDIFF(day, nt.[POST-DATE], GETDATE()) AS LateDays
FROM
    pub1_nomtrans nt
WHERE 
    ([UNDONE-FLAG] = 0) 
    AND ([POST-TYPE] = N'BC') 
    AND ([CONTRA-CODE] = N'X20') 
    AND (ISNULL([BILLED-PAID-FLAG], N'') <> 'C') 
    AND [Reference] = '1800509'
GROUP BY 
    nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], nt.[POST-DATE]
```

This currently returns 2 rows:

```
MT-CODE REFERENCE   LateDays
----------------------------
012790/0033 1800509    93
012790/0033 1800509    89
```

What I would like to do is do a join on itself so that I get the maximum late days figure for each row - i.e. the output for this query should be:

```
MT-CODE REFERENCE   LateDays
----------------------------
012790/0033 1800509    93
```

Any pointers gratefully received.

Thank you

Comment: You could use offset/ top with an order by if we assume you only get 1 record back each time. row_number/cross apply if you get multiple back but want top N for each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't really need the group by in your current query, and you don't really need a self join. You can use your current query as a derived table and do a group by on it's results:

```
SELECT [MT-CODE], [REFERENCE], MAX(LateDays)
FROM
(
    SELECT nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], DATEDIFF(day, nt.[POST-DATE], GETDATE()) AS LateDays
    from pub1_nomtrans nt
    WHERE ([UNDONE-FLAG] = 0) AND ([POST-TYPE] = N'BC') AND ([CONTRA-CODE] = N'X20') AND (ISNULL([BILLED-PAID-FLAG], N'') <> 'C') 
    AND [Reference]='1800509'
) x
GROUP BY [MT-CODE], [REFERENCE]
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this and thanks for formatting my question better :) I have tried this query but it is saying there is incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

Comment: Add table alias like 'a' after closing bracket. `...) a`

Comment: I realised I needed to add an alias to the sub query :)  Thanks again!

Comment: SELECT nt2.[MT-CODE], nt2.[REFERENCE], MAX(nt2.LateDays)
FROM
(
    SELECT nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], DATEDIFF(day, nt.[POST-DATE], GETDATE()) AS LateDays
    from pub1_nomtrans nt
    WHERE ([UNDONE-FLAG] = 0) AND ([POST-TYPE] = N'BC') AND ([CONTRA-CODE] = N'X20') AND (ISNULL([BILLED-PAID-FLAG], N'') <> 'C') 
    AND [Reference]='1800509'
) nt2
GROUP BY [MT-CODE], [REFERENCE]

Comment: Glad to help. I've added an alias to the derived table (I always forget that part :-))

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this..

You could use offset / top with an order by if we assume you only get 1 record back each time. row_number/cross apply if you get multiple back but want top N for each record.

I didn't give the cross apply example but it basically says for each row in your base set, return the N rows from the second set  we could make N be the top row and order it by the LateDays; thus getting the latest ldate day data for each record.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], 
    DATEDIFF(day, nt.[POST-DATE], GETDATE()) AS LateDays
FROM
    pub1_nomtrans nt
WHERE 
    ([UNDONE-FLAG] = 0) 
    AND ([POST-TYPE] = N'BC') 
    AND ([CONTRA-CODE] = N'X20') 
    AND (ISNULL([BILLED-PAID-FLAG], N'') <> 'C') 
    AND [Reference] = '1800509'
GROUP BY 
    nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], nt.[POST-DATE]
ORDER BY LateDays DESC
```

or

```
SELECT 
    nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], 
    DATEDIFF(day, nt.[POST-DATE], GETDATE()) AS LateDays
FROM
    pub1_nomtrans nt
WHERE 
    ([UNDONE-FLAG] = 0) 
    AND ([POST-TYPE] = N'BC') 
    AND ([CONTRA-CODE] = N'X20') 
    AND (ISNULL([BILLED-PAID-FLAG], N'') <> 'C') 
    AND [Reference] = '1800509'
GROUP BY 
    nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], nt.[POST-DATE]
ORDER BY LateDays DESC
FETCH NEXT 1
```

OR  - if multiple records back with different mt/reference values and you want the max late days for each.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], 
    DATEDIFF(day, nt.[POST-DATE], GETDATE()) AS LateDays
    row_number() over (partition by nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE] order by DATEDIFF(day, nt.[POST-DATE], GETDATE() DESC) as RN
FROM
    pub1_nomtrans nt
WHERE 
    ([UNDONE-FLAG] = 0) 
    AND ([POST-TYPE] = N'BC') 
    AND ([CONTRA-CODE] = N'X20') 
    AND (ISNULL([BILLED-PAID-FLAG], N'') <> 'C') 
    AND [Reference] = '1800509'
GROUP BY 
    nt.[MT-CODE], nt.[REFERENCE], nt.[POST-DATE])
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```